# mounting share in fstab error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, network-shares, mount, fstab

I've been successfully able to mount a share on my Ubuntu Server using this command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //IPTOSHARE/DriveLetter$/Folder/"Folder Space" /mnt/Folder/"Folder Space" -o username="",domain=""
```

However this only mounts the share until reboot.

I have tried to mount in fstab:

```
//IPTOSHARE/DriveLetter$/Folder/"Folder Space" /mnt/Folder/"Folder Space" cifs credentials=/home/username/.smbcredentials,uid=username,gid=sharegroup 0 0
```

However unlike the successful temporary mount, fstab does not like the following characters that WORKED on the temporary mount: $ ""

DriveLetter$ -Hidden share
"Folder Space" - Folder that has a space in it. I know this is NOT idea but its what I have to work with.

Why can I successfully create a temporary share, but not a permanent share using fstab?

Comment: just place your command over at `/etc/rc.local` or whatever your distro runs user init scripts and you're done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @Marcel suggests would work, but isn't best practice.

To use spaces in your fstab file, you need to use the octal ascii notation for a space:

```
\040
```

So for your uses, it would look like:

```
//IP/Drive/Folder/Folder\040Name /mnt/Folder/Folder\040Name cifs creds... 0 0
```

Try adding that, then running:

```
sudo mount -a
```

And post back specific errors mentioned if they exist.